# i want to populate my edit form with the data of the selected item

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sails.js

```
<div class="section" ng-app="ShopMod" ng-controller="myShopsCtrl">
  <a class="btn btn-primary btn-fill" href="/addshop">Add a new Shop</a>
  <br>
  <hr>
  <div ng-init="getMyShops()">
    <div class="row">
      <div ng-repeat="shop in shops">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-sm-12">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="front">
              <div class="cover">
                <img src="images/city.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
              </div>
              <div class="user">
                <img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="images/default-avatar.png"/>
              </div>
              <div class="content">
                <div class="main">
                  <h3 class="name">{{shop.owner}}</h3>
                  <h5><i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-fw text-muted"></i> {{shop.address}}, {{shop.state}}</h5>
                  <h5><i class="fa fa-building-o fa-fw text-muted"></i> {{shop.contact}}</h5>
                  <h5><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw text-muted"></i> {{shop.email}}</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="footer">
                  <a href="/editshop/:{{shop.id}}">
                    Edit |
                  </a>
                  <a ng-click="manageShop(shop.id)">
                    Manage |
                  </a>
                  <a ng-click="editShop(shop.id)">
                    Delete
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div> <!-- end front panel -->
          </div> <!-- end card -->
        </div> <!-- end card-container -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I'm new to sails and angular and i'm having an issue populating my edit form. I have a list of items, code is above. the user clicks the edit link and it takes them to a page,code is below, that will be populated with the data of that selected item.

```
<div class="section" ng-app="ShopMod" ng-controller="editShopCtrl">
  <div class="header text-center">
    <h2 style="text-decoration: underline">Edit Shop</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <form ng-submit="updateShop()">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Shop Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="name" value="{{shop.name}}">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="address">Shop Address</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="address" value="{{shop.address}}">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="contact">Phone Number</label>
        <input type="tel" class="form-control"  ng-model="contact" value="{{shop.contact}}">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="email">Shop Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control"  ng-model="email" value="{{shop.email}}">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="email">State</label>
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="state" value="{{shop.state}}">
          <option>Lagos</option>
          <option>Abuja</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-info">Update Shop</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

I know how to get the id of the selected item, and pass it to my back-end controller, my issue is sending that data back from my back-end controller to my form which is basically another view.Below is my function for getting the id from the url,finding the corresponding data and returning it.

```
  editShop:function (req, res)
  {
    var id = req.param('id');

    Shops.findOne({id:id},
    function (err, shop)
    {
      if(err)
      {
        return res.negotiate(err);
      }

      return res.send(shop.data)
    })
  }
```

Below is the code for how i'm handling the routing

```
 'GET /editshop/:id':{
    view:'Shops/editShop',
    locals: {
      layout: '/Dashboard/layout-admin',
    }
  }
```

i would like to know how to go about dealing with this situation.

Comment: where is your angular's code!!!

Answer (score 0):

According to your scenario on click you want to load another page with edit layout. Ejs lets you bind the data you want at backend And so that you can send the data after bind.

But i do it different way.

> **SAVE All Detail to localStorage of the browser**

I am completing only some of your code you can easily see where and what you should do.....

```
angular.module('ShopMod', [])
    .controller('myShopsCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
      $scope.getMyShops = function (id) {
        $http.get('/shops?id=' + id)
            .then(function (res) {
              if (Array === res.data.constructor)//if res.data is array
                $scope.shop = res.data[0];
              else //res.data is object.
                $scope.shop = res.data;
              localStorage.setItem('myShop', JSON.stringify($scope.shop));
            }, function (err) {
              $scope.shop = {};
              console.log(err);
            });
      }
    }]);
```

In the above...

1. `GET request` is made at lcalhost:1337/shops?id=43 (Let shop id is
   43).which is a `blueprint route`(sails make it for you by default
   for rapid development).
2. `$scope.shop` is initialized with res.data and the same is saved in browsers localStorage by key **myShop**.Which you can access anytime.(you can see local storage in developer console Resources).

So all you have to do is to load the edit page.

```
<div class="footer">
    <a href="/editshop/">
        Edit |
    </a>
    <a ng-click="manageShop(shop.id)">
        Manage |
    </a>
    <a ng-click="editShop(shop.id)">
        Delete
    </a>
</div>
```

Back-end Route for loading edit template.

```
'GET /editshop/':{
    view:'Shops/editShop',
    locals: {
      layout: '/Dashboard/layout-admin',
    }
  }
```

In your edit template.
make `ng-init="initializeForm()"` at top.
and write controller function.

```
angular.module('ShopMod', [])
    .controller('editShopCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
      $scope.getMyShops = function (id) {
        $scope.shop=JSON.parse(localStorage.myShop);
      }
    }]);
```

Putting data from localStorage to current `$scope.shop`...

This is how i do!I hope it will work for you!